# vba excel - find string wildcard

Tags: string, excel, vba, wildcard

I am doing a simple search engine in excel and I want to make some wildcards, for example:

I have a cell where the user input the search term (only numbers) which should look like this: "123456".
then, I have another workbook, where I search for the "123456" exactly. this I managed to do.

however, how can I make wildcards? for example, I want the user to be able to search for: "123?56" and I will give him the results of: "123456", "123356", "123556" etc.

this is how I look for the exact match:

```
set rFound = wks.UserRange.Find(strToSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlwhole, MatchCase:=False)
```

any ideas?

thank you

Comment: Do you want to get the first match  or possible matches ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a wildcard either in a loop or with `Find`:

```
Sub dural2()
    MsgBox Range("A1:A10").Find(What:="123*56", After:=Range("A1")).Row
End Sub
```

[image]

or in a loop with `Like`:

```
Sub dural()
    For Each r In Range("A1:A10")
        If r.Value Like "123*56" Then
            MsgBox r.Address
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, works allmost perfect, though when I do two wildcrads like this: "123*_5_*7" it may also give me stuff like this: "1233447" - notice that it gave a result that shouldn't appear @Gary's

Comment: It should be noted that the two examples given above do not always behave the same. In the Find example, the first cell to be searched is the cell AFTER the first cell, i.e. A2. If more than one value in the range matches the search text, and one of those values is in cell A1, the two examples will behave differently, with the Find returning the address of the second instance, and the loop returning the address of the first instance (A1).