# Search by Keywords Using Wildcards in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I know that this is possible to do with CTRL-F, but I want to be able to do it in VBA. For example, if I wanted to search for "Worthington Pump" in my workbook, but no where in the workbook are those two words in that order, but they are in the same cell, so I could search for "Worthington *Pump*". Is there any way to do this using VBA instead of CTRL-F?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vba excel - find string wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35538493/vba-excel-find-string-wildcard)

Comment: Why not just use the `Range.Find()` method in VBA? `Find` and `FindNext` together allow you to do everything that you can do with CTRL+F.

Answer (score 3):

Let's suppose that `rng` is the range you want to search.

```
For Each c In rng
    If InStr(c.Value, "Worthington") > 0 And InStr(c.Value, "Pump") > 0 Then
        'some code to highlight cell
    End If
Next c
```

Think that code would do the trick for you :)

Answer (score 3):

InString searches are fantastic, and important to learn, but another option is to use the Range.Find Method which I would highly encourage you get familiar with.  Here's a link to the MSDN Documentation: [Range.Find Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel)

The wildcard character is the Asterisks (*) and you can place it before, inbetween, or after the string of your choice.  My examples below will find the and select the first cell it finds where the text has "Worthington" or "Pump" *ANYWHERE* in it.

Incredibly useful method to learn.

```
Range("A1:A10").Find(What:="*Worthington*").Select
'Do Stuff'
```

OR

```
Range("A1:A10").Find(What:="*Pump*").Select
'Do Stuff'
```