# Wildcards in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, wildcard

Is there a way to do something similar to `Cells.find().Activate`, but that uses *wildcards*. I have a drop down list and I want to find and activate the cell on another sheet that has a similar name. For example, in the drop down list there is *Muskoka D* but on the other sheet it is *District of Muskoka*. Is that possible?

Comment: Posible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35538493/vba-excel-find-string-wildcard

Comment: Your example does not fit into a wildcard scenario, and unfortunately it doesn't really fit a regex pattern either, so you'd basically have to do fuzz-searching (slow...) which mind you there are many options for that but maybe not in VBA.

Comment: Note: `Range.Find().AnythingAfterThatMethodCall` is a very bad idea: you're *asking* for run-time error 91 to be thrown whenever `Find` doesn't find a match. **ALWAYS** test if your search result `Is Nothing` before making any member calls on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it if you change how your drop down list is. If `Muskoka D` was just `Muskoka` you could do the following.

In the query of the other dataset do the following in the Column that would contain `District of Muskoka`

```
Like "*" & <Drop Down Select Value> & "*"
```

In our case it would be `Muskoka`

```
Like "*" & "Muskoka" & "*"
```

Would yield all rows that have `Muskoka` in it. In your example it would yield `District of Muskoka` and `DistrictofMuskoka` and `MustacheMuskokaDistrict`. Basically anything with `Muskoka`

Comment: @YowE3K tyvm for fixing my errors. I need to pay more attention to detail.